# List of Input Values which will cause the "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected..." error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I know the **<** and **>** characters will cause this error, **but what other characters/inputs will cause this error?**

I'm testing for this error in the Global.asax, and reridrecting to an error page where I want to list all possible values which cause this error, so the user can go back to their page and get rid of them.

I've done some googling, but all I see so far are the **<** and **>** characters...surely there are more out there.

Comment: I know its really really late, but I added an answer with a complete list.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
 ASP.NET helps protect against script exploits that are disguised as URLs by
 checking for potentially dangerous strings, such as "<!", "</", and "<?".
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1sw53ds.aspx

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestvalidationexception.aspx

*Update: This answer was based on .net 4.0.; for updated tags see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25405146/14753*

Comment: so they all start with a < bracket then?

Comment: This answer is incomplete, and based on a poor assumption.

Comment: No, they don't all start with a bracket.  A `%` and a `*` triggered it for me recently.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman I updated the answer to reflect the version this related to

Answer (score 15):

Here is the actual complete list of inputs that will cause the error:

```
<(any a-z character)  
<!  
</
<?
&#
```

Note that an angle bracket on it own '<' will not cause an exception.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370415/how-to-check-if-string-will-fire-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was) that has a more complete answer including some code, which is where I derived the list from.

Of course you could always look [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/CrossSiteScriptingValidation.cs) for the rest of it if you are concerned.

Comment: Of course, since this is undocumented it could be changed at some point in the future.

Comment: @Rawling Same goes for the other answers.  I updated with a link to the actual source, which counts as documentation in my book.

Comment: Regular expression for Javascript validation: /(\<[a-z!/?])|(&#)/ig

Answer (score 4):

No, < is not the only character combination that will cause it.  &# will cause it as well.

Comment: +1, ran into an issue with this exact combination (&#) today and looking for a full list of strings that cause the error

Comment: @Mercurybullet: There is a new answer that has been posted with a full list.