# How to check if string will fire “A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected…” error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760574/list-of-input-values-which-will-cause-the-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form) but I don't care so much about what characters will/won't cause the error to fire.  I'm more curious as to what method I can call, to check for myself, if the current string will fire the above error message.

To give a bit of background, I'm creating random passwords when a user forgets theirs and needs a reset.  Unfortunately, the random password generator "accidentally" created one with `&#` in it recently.  This caused the page to break when the user tried to login with it.

As mentioned in plenty of posts around this topic, `ValidateRequest=false` (or `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` for .NET 4.0) can be used to turn off .NET checking for these exploits, but I don't see any reason to lose this extra layer of security when I'm the one creating the string in the first place.  And simply telling the random generator to re-randomize on an incomplete list (`<`, `&#`, etc) doesn't seem like the cleanest solution so I'd like to use the same method of checking that .NET is using.

Microsoft's explanation of what exploits are in question and what is being done to guard against them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1sw53ds.aspx).

[This guy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972967.aspx) talks about finding a function called `IsDangerousString` after digging in with Reflector, but I'm not able to find this function to use it.  Also he's referring to .NET 1.1 and I'm working with .NET 3.5

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't see a reason why you would include such obscure characters. I'd probably use the RandomNumberGenerator class to fill a byte[] and then use a z-base32 encoder to encode the bytes to a string.

Comment: you know the "exploit" character you want to allow why not Html Encode  them before post and then html decode them back

Comment: @Shelakel Sure, there are plenty of other ways to generate random passwords.  Unfortunately, however, we are stuck needing to fulfill all 4 of the 4 character rules (lowercase, uppercase, number, special char) with passwords for this project.  Of course, I could just remove the offending "obscure" characters, but since the spec isn't very clear I'd like to use the same function the system is to check.

Comment: @HatSoft valid point, though this sounds like extra overhead when I could just be more careful about the string I send to the user in the first place.

Comment: @Mercurybullet I suggest replace the characters with new ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ASP.NET class that validates requests is `System.Web.CrossSiteScriptingValidation`, and the method you want is `IsDangerousString`. Unfortunately, both are marked `internal`, so you can't access them directly. You have several options:

**Option 1:** Call `IsDangerousString` via Reflection. However, Microsoft could change the method at any time, which would break your applicaton.

**Option 2:** Decompile `IsDangerousString` and copy it to your own application. See the code below.

**Option 3:** Call [`Membership.GeneratePassword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword.aspx). This returns a password that is guaranteed to pass request validation.

Excerpts from the ASP.NET `CrossSiteScriptingValidation` class (via .NET Reflector):

```
private static char[] startingChars = new char[] { '<', '&' };

internal static bool IsDangerousString(string s, out int matchIndex)
{
    matchIndex = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        int num2 = s.IndexOfAny(startingChars, startIndex);
        if (num2 < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (num2 == (s.Length - 1))
        {
            return false;
        }
        matchIndex = num2;
        char ch = s[num2];
        if (ch != '&')
        {
            if ((ch == '<') && ((IsAtoZ(s[num2 + 1]) || (s[num2 + 1] == '!')) || ((s[num2 + 1] == '/') || (s[num2 + 1] == '?'))))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (s[num2 + 1] == '#')
        {
            return true;
        }
        startIndex = num2 + 1;
    }
}

private static bool IsAtoZ(char c)
{
    return (((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) || ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Since the function is internal and I won't be able to access it directly for updates, is there any reason not to just use the following regex (with ignoreCase)? `\<[a-z!/?]|&#`

Comment: The regex is equivalent to Option 2, only much more concise. :-) This is probably the best you can do for now. In the next version of ASP.NET, though, you'll be able to skip validation for certain fields by using the [HttpRequest.Unvalidated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.unvalidated(v=VS.110).aspx) property.

Comment: Seems to filter `<script` but does allow `< script` (with space)

Comment: @Marcel: In an HTML tag, spaces aren't allowed after `<`, so `< script>` is harmless.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript function based on Option 2 in @Michael Liu's answer:

```
function isDangerousString(s) { return s.match(/<[a-zA-Z!/?]|&#/) !== null; }
```