# Practical danger in turning off Request Validation for a Form/POST field?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

We have an ASP.NET MVC application, and are currently running into some cases where (randomly-generated) user passwords contain "dangerous" cross-site-scripting character sequences (e.g. "<?" and "<!", see [List of Input Values which will cause the "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected..." error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760574/list-of-input-values-which-will-cause-the-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form) for a discussion on all).

We'd like to allow users to continue to use these strings as part of their passwords, but also not expose ourselves to any legitimate scripting threat.

The login credentials are collected in a (Razor view) form and submitted via HttpPost (over TLS). Our handling MVC Action (C#) hashes the user identifier and password, and then queries the DB (via EntityFramework and LINQ) for a record with that hash value (there's a little more to this to avoid hash collisions, but none of the user-entered values are being passed to the DB).

We know we can disable request validation at various levels (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx), but can't find any definitive discussion on where the risk actually lies.

Since the dangerous values (the plaintext password) are being submitted via POST and not GET, I'm assuming there's no risk during transmission from client to server.

Since we're hashing the value in C# before doing anything else with it, as well as using EntityFramework rather than building an ad-hoc query, and never displaying the user-entered value in HTML, I'm assuming there's no risk during our processing/Action.

In fact, if I'm understanding the goal of Request Validation correctly, we'd only be exposing ourselves to risk here if we disabled request validation AND did one of the following with the user input:

- a non-parameterized ad-hoc SQL query with the value (e.g. `string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE f='" + user_value + "'; // this is ALWAYS a terrible idea`)
- a webservice call or GET redirect (e.g. `Response.Redirect("https://domain.tld/api/svc?param=" + user_value);`)
- used/displayed the value in generated HTML/JS/CSS/XML/etc (e.g. `<p>Entered: @Model.PlaintextPassword</p>`)

Are there other risks to disabling Request Validation on a small scale (specific fields or actions, not the entire project/site) that I'm missing? Is the Login Page scenario outlined above a valid use of disabling this validation, or should we instead find a way to encode the value before posting?

Comment: Request validation is a blanket measure to reduce your susceptibility to these kinds of attacks across the board - whether they are an issue depends of course on what you are doing with the submitted information. If all you're doing with the submitted value is computing a hash and comparing it to something then there is likely no risk involved.

Comment: I don't think there are any risks as you don't render the password directly on client in its unhashed form. It would be a risk if you render a text where could possibly be <script>some js code</script> and don't HTML Encode it so the browser would think it's a valid code to be executed when in fact it's a threat.